# Firefox userChrome.css window focus selector

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, userchrome.css

Is there a CSS selector I can use in `userChrome.css` to change the text color of Firefox when the whole browser window loses focus?

I've tried:

```
window:focus element { color: #aaa; }    /* does nothing */
window:active element { color: #aaa; }   /* only when something's being clicked */
window:hover element { color: #aaa; }    /* only when the cursor is over the window */
window[focus] element { color: #aaa; }   /* wishful thinking--doesn't work */
window[active="true"] element { color: #aaa; }   /* documented to work... */
```

Or am I stuck using Javascript? If so, is there a `userChrome.js` that I can put that script in?

Comment: If `:focus` doesnt work try `:active` and also try `:hover` the `[focus]` wont work because i dont see an attribute changing as the browser is focused or not.

Comment: @Noitidart: Thanks for your interest in my question. `:active` checks if anything is being clicked on.  `:hover` checks if the mouse is inside the window.  `[focus]` was just wishful thinking.  Do you know of a way to easily add some JS the way you do CSS with `userChrome.css`?

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Themes/Obsolete/Theme_changes_in_Firefox_3.5#Supporting_3.5_Features, `[active="true"]` should work...but it doesn't.

Comment: Ahah! It's changed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-window-inactive .  Now it's `:-moz-window-inactive`.

Comment: So the change was post Firefox 3.5 right? So it's safe to use `-moz-window-inactive` if I want to target Firefox 4+?

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-window-inactive, this functionality has been changed.

Now you can use:

```
element:-moz-window-inactive { color: #aaa; }
```

and:

```
element:not(-moz-window-inactive) { color: #aaa; }
```

To change CSS styles depending on if the Firefox window is focused.

Comment: How to achieve this in Firefox 89+?